# Рекуррентная формула C++. Общий член ряда

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такое вот задание. Подскажите пожалуйста формулу для общего члена данного ряда, вожусь уже долго, но так и не доходит

Comment: Не понял... ну ведь x^n/n!...? И, кстати, если писать нормально - там **НЕ НУЖНЫ** подпрограммы ни для возведения в степень, ни для факториала...

Comment: Как вариант - можно использовать три накопительные переменные, одна для общей суммы, и ещё две, одна для числителя, одна для знаменателя.

Comment: Вот вам, допустим, рекуррентная ф-ла `return (условие)? f(x,a*x,b*n,n+1)+a/b:0` отдельно ведём числитель а, отдельно знаменатель b. Но не запрещено проще `return (условие)?f(x,n+1) + степень(x,n)/факториал(x,n):0`; Условия бывают двух видов, чаще всего проверка на эпсилон, но может быть на к-во шагов.

Comment: А главное - при использовании рекуррентной формулы подпрограммы оказываются не нужны...

Answer (score 1):

Про общую формулу уже сказали, а рекуррентная формула, о которой говорится в заголовке, для k-го члена ряда:

```
 A(k) = A(k-1) * x / k
```